# Remote desktop connection domain name SEO

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, iis6

I have a website that has a domain name such like `www.example.com` which is of course the website. Then there is `example.com` which is used by my boss for remote desktop connection. I was wondering if this will be a problem for SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO it won't, the RDP uses a specific port that is not part of the usual SEO crawling.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue is if `example.com` and `www.example.com` show the same content without the correct 301 redirect, then there is the potential for a duplicate content penalty.

RDP wont have any effect as its on a different port,